# White background seen during page transition in an android app

Tags: android, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

During page transitions white background is flickering which looks very bad in the app.....
I've tried setting the following CSS property

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

as well as

```
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning,
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-page {
    overflow: visible;
```

}

But both of these does not work in my case....
I'm using android 4.1 and jquery in my app...
Anyone has any suggestions, I would be thankful to you.....

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the transition, is it animated? Only certain css 3 operations will make use of the GPU on the device. eg -webkit-transform:transform3d(0, 1, 1, 5deg)

Comment: I have not used any of the transitions as far as I know. I am using jquery may be by default some transition might be placed, but i don't know what....Any suggestions,please...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want page transitions, maybe you need to use

$.mobile.changePage('#yourPage', "none");
???

If doesn't resolved, see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html